# unable to open removable drive with this error "Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again."

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

i am trying to connect removable drive but it unable to open removable drive with this error "Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again."

Comment: Be aware of case sensitivity and/or spaces in the file-name.

Comment: What exactly did you try?  We need details to answer.

Comment: when i am trying to connect removable drive with ubuntu 14.04 i got that error